# how can i convert NSNumber to CLLocationDistance?

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, formatter, cllocationdistance

I have to convert an `NSNumber` to `CLLocationDistance` for comparing them. So are there any formatter to do that? I searched at internet but i could not find.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605620/problems-converting-data-in-cllocationdistance

Comment: As far as i understand, in that question person tries to add a CLLocationDistance to his NSArray and answer suggest him to convert a distance to NSNumber. But i am trying to convert a NSNumber to CLLocatinDistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLLocationDistance` is really just a `double`. All you need is this:

```
NSNumber *number = ... // some number
CLLocationDistance distance = ... // some distance

if (distance == [number doubleValue]) {
    // they are equal
}
```

Keep in mind that comparing two `double` values for equality can appear to fail due to the inexactness of most `double` values.

```
if (abs(distance - [number doubleValue]) <= DBL_EPSILON) {
    // they are equal
}
```

Comment: Can you compare `floats` or `doubles` using `==`? As far as I know you should subtract them, `abs` the result and compare them to an Epsilon value. ;)

Comment: You can use `==` but as I stated, it may fail in many cases. Your suggestion is exactly the solution to my warning at the end of my answer.